# How to use ws-security info per sending soap message in CXF?

Tags: java, cxf

I like to be able to dynamically change/set the ws-security info per sending soap message in cxf. How can this best be done.

Details: I want to change settings like keystore name, keystore alias, password, host name, etc.. during runtime, preferable per sending message.
Currently I am using: jaxws client with WSS4JOutInterceptor and WSS4JInInterceptor interceptor for signing. And I am using http conduit with tls client parameters for SSL/TLS communications.
Both the jaxws client and http conduit are configured in spring and have their configuration like keystore name, alias and password set in the Spring config.

I see options:
1) I change these settings during runtime through a global property.
2) I change these settings per sending message (preferable).

2) Is preferable but most difficult I think.
How should I do this?

I was thinking about: 
a) jaxws client: make my own in- and out interceptor that intercepts a message and use the correct (cached) WSS4JOutInterceptor interceptor depending on the security settings that that message requires. If the WSS4JOutInterceptor interceptor doesn't exists in cache, it's created (I probably have max 5 WSS4JOutInterceptor instances cached).
However, how can I determine which settings are required in my interceptor as that is known in an other part of the app when talking to the @Webservice proxy to create and send the soap request/message... 
Maybe I could be able to add some kind of securityInfo object to the soap message through the JaxWsClientProxy, but how ?... 
Or maybe I can set the interceptors when sending/creating the soap message when this security info is still know. This will then be a light weight interceptor containing the required settings, linking to the cached interceptors, that is selected depending on the settings...

b) http conduit:  using a ConduitSelector (never used it but will find out), such that I am able to select the correct http conduit, but I have the same problem as in (a): "How to determine which settings I should use" as they are known when creating/sending a soap message and the interceptors are set later...
Probably I have to set an conduit selector per sending message..

At the end the above become a big story ;), but I hope it's clear you have can give some advice?

Comment: This was cross-posted on the Apache CXF mailing list and got more discussion there: http://www.mail-archive.com/users@cxf.apache.org/msg29770.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found the `org.apache.cxf` packages to be very helpful in keeping me from having to write custom classes and have been able to stick to the basic interface.

For your instance, the approach might look like:

- use a `JAX-WS` or `wsimport` client
- use the `cxf` `WSS4JOutInterceptor` with dynamic properties
- use a dynamic `CallbackHandler` class for access to the keystore

A typical (`wsimport`'d) client public API might look like:

```
public class SomeServiceClient
{

  public SomeService getSomeService( URL url )
  {

    SomeService_Service svc = new SomeService_Service();

    SomeService someService = svc.getSomeServicePort();

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient( someService );
    Endpoint cxfEP = client.getEndpoint();

    Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    outProps.put( WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature" );
    outProps.put( WSHandlerConstants.USER, "foo" );
    outProps.put( WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, SomeClientCallbackHandler.class.getName() );
    outProps.put( WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "client-sign.properties" );

    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor( outProps );

    cxfEP.getOutInterceptors().add( wssOut );

    return someService;
  }
}
```

You could provide some logic to determine which `WSHandlerConstants.USER` value to pass, which `PW_CALLBACK_CLASS` to use, and which `SIG_PROP_FILE` to use.

The properties file could look like the following. You could simply have multiple files to choose from, or you could just dynamically add these properties in the class:

```
# properties for accessing the java keystore using Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=bar
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=foo
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=foobar.keystore
```

Finally, your `CallbackHandler` will need to provide the password for the alias of the cert you identified in the keystore. This could also have some dynamic logic in it.

```
public class SomeClientCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler
{

    @Override
    public void handle( Callback[] callbacks ) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException
    {
        for( Callback thisCallback : callbacks )
        {
            WSPasswordCallback pwcb = (WSPasswordCallback)thisCallback;
            String user = pwcb.getIdentifier();
            int usage = pwcb.getUsage();

            if( usage == WSPasswordCallback.SIGNATURE )
            {
                if( "foo".equals( user ) ) pwcb.setPassword( "bar" );
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

In the end, there is not much more work to make this all 'dynamic' to handle multiple keystores versus the work needed to just do it once. It might be preferable over coding your own 'in' or 'out' interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answers to this question appear to be (from http://www.mail-archive.com/users@cxf.apache.org/msg29804.html):

> Hi Ed,
>
> As I already wrote, you don't even need the interceptor to change the 
>   properties. You can do it in your client by sending message:
>
> AddNumbers port = (AddNumbers)service.getPort(portName,
>   AddNumbers.class); 
>   ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.ENCRYPT_PROPERTIES,
>   ).
>
> Although, If you would like to do it in interceptor, you can pass
>   necessary  information with message properties using the same technic.
>
> The most standard and recommended way to control security in CXF is
>   using  WS-Policy. You also can apply it dynamically at the runtime. If
>   this way is interesting  for you, I can provide further information
>   how to set WS-Policy dynamically.
>
> Cheers, Andrei.

(from http://www.mail-archive.com/users@cxf.apache.org/msg29809.html):

> If you do:
>   ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("thread.local.request.context",
>   "true");
>
> than future calls to getRequestContext() will use a thread local
>   request  context. That allows the request context to be threadsafe.
>   (Note: the response  context is always thread local in CXF).
>
> Details in
>   http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAXWSclientproxiesthreadsafe%3F
>
> Cheers, Andrei.